# Is there a way to cast youtube videos inside my application?

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm using the "TheMovieDB" API to get information about movies, and it is possible to retrieve video information for a certain movie, like this:

```
videos: {
results: [
{
id: "533ec6a5c3a3685448005327",
iso_639_1: "en",
key: "ac7KhViaVqc",
name: "First Trailer",
site: "YouTube",
size: 720,
type: "Trailer"
}
]
}
```

As you can see, it is possible to build the youtube video url with the key provided in the JSON.

When building the MediaInfo object, you can pass the video URL, like this:

```
MediaInfo.Builder(MOVIE_URL)
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("video/mp4")
                .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                .build();
```

However, if MOVIE_URL is the youtube url, I can't cast the content.

Is it possible to cast youtube videos from my app? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no APIs in the cast SDK to accomplish that. People have had different degrees of luck with using the embedded youtube iframe approach, but that is not a perfect solution for various reasons; for example you cannot skip ads, etc.